# Bad access on UICollectionViewController instantiation

Tags: ios, swift

Before my app was crashing, this is how I was setting up my view controller to be presented, and it was working fine:

```
var form: MainFormViewController?

func addTapped() {
    //        form?.delegate = self
    form = MainFormViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: form!)

    navigationController?.present(nav, animated: true)
}
```

I retyped this so something may look unordinary, but you get the idea.

But now I want to instantiate this view controller right away.  So I added this code and got `BAD ACCESS` code 2.

[image]

Also, when I tried `super.init(layout)` on my collection view, I got bad access on that too.  I don't know if these two events are related.

**MainFormViewController.swift** has no `init`.  I setup in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    //        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1176, green: 0.251, blue: 0.4863, alpha: 1)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1176, green: 0.251, blue: 0.4863, alpha: 1)

    let stopButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .stop, target: self, action: #selector(stopTapped))
    stopButton.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(stopButton, animated: true)


    collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: stockCellId)
    collectionView?.register(MainFormCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: formCellId)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

**I am not using storyboards**

Uh I think I need `init`s in all my `UICollectionViewController`s.  That seems to be the problem, correct?

Comment: Do you have a crash log?

Comment: @Larme Not sure.  nothing pops up in the console besides `Unknown class _TtC7FitApp314ViewController in Interface Builder file.
(lldb) `

Comment: is there any navigation controller in storyboard?

Comment: @SaurabhJain Yes.  Subclasses of `BaseCollectionViewController` are embedded in navigation controllers

Comment: @SaurabhJain And then when a button is tapped, as you can see above, I create another one.  Now that I think about it, I am not sure why I do that.

Comment: Could you paste some code from `MainFormViewController`? How do you want to create it? You have your own init or is it defined in the storyboard?

Comment: Thanks! you want to present the `MainFormViewController ` from the `BaseCollectionViewController` as far as I understand. Is that correct? You should not need any special initializers, so I dont think that is the problem

Comment: @CatalinaT. Mm yes.  I just figured it would make more sense to initialize it, but it works perfectly fine the other way, so I'll take your advice.  thanks!